# Steps to take a test on Passport Laravel

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-passport

What procedure must I follow to test Laravel. With which road should I start? Which controller would I need?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When posting on stackoverflow you need to have reproduce able code, so people in theory could run it. In this it is very open, what is testing for whole Laravel even, there is multiple approaches. A way to make the question more concise would be to show some controller logic you have a hard time testing.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In fact I do not have a specific code yet but I want to know in general what steps to follow to re-realize a test on laravel passport.

Comment: What do you mean by "re-realize a test on laravel passport" ?

Comment: Do a unit test on Laravel Passport.